# Trying to create a type from a class causes an error even when I create the variable correctly

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement an email system that I found in a tutorial.

My `EmailMessage` class looks like this:

```
public class EmailMessage
{
    public EmailMessage()
    {
        ToAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>();
    }

    public List<EmailAddress> ToAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

And the `EmailAddress` class looks like this:

```
public class EmailAddress
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

So now I'm trying to construct a test email message.

I create a test 'toAddress':

```
EmailAddress toAddress = new EmailAddress()
{
    Name = "Fred Flintsone",
    Address = "cmt34@pitt.edu"
};
```

But when trying to construct the test EmailMessage like this:

```
var message = new EmailMessage()
{
    ToAddresses = toAddress,
    Content = "Hey this is a test",
};
```

I am getting this error when I try to assign the 'toAddress' to 'ToAddresses' of EmailMessage:

> Cannot implicitly convert type MyEmailProject.Classes.EmailAddress to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems pretty clear. The _ToAddresses_ is a List of EmailAddress but you are trying to set it to a single EmailAddress. You just need to _ToAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>{ toAddress},_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already initialized `ToAddresses` list in `EmailMessage` constructor, you can just call [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netcore-3.1) method to add `toAddress`

```cs
var message = new EmailMessage
{
    Content = "Hey this is a test"
};
message.ToAddresses.Add(toAddress);
```

There is not need to create a list again, if it's already created, because you can loose the previously added items

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work because `ToAddresses` is a `List` and not an `EmailAddress`. You need to do something like this:

```
var message = new EmailMessage()
{
    ToAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>(){ toAddress },
    Content = "Hey this is a test",

};
```